# dynamically resize google map bounds

Tags: google-maps

OK, here's the situation:
I have a relatively small map of 350px x 350px. I have coordinate data for all congressional districts in a certain state. I have created a google map with controls that allow me to select a district type (state house, state senate, us house) and then select a particular district. This fires an event which, in turn, executes a function that retreives the coordinate data that describes that district, creates a polygon from the data and displays it on the map. All this is well and good except for the the fact that the widely varying shapes and sizes sometimes results in the polygon being too small (or too big, depending on zoom level). I have attempted repeatedly to find a way to dynamically resize the bounds of the map to no avail. Here is my most recent attempt. Unfortunately, fitBounds will insist upon adding that infuriating padding. Can anyone help? Maybe a trig genius out there has a solution? I should also mention that all user controls are disabled because this is for automatic generation of PDFs.

```
PdfGenerator.data.currentPolygon.setMap(PdfGenerator.data.smallMap);

overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function() {};
overlay.setMap(PdfGenerator.data.smallMap);

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(PdfGenerator.data.smallMap, 'idle', function() {
    swCoords = overlay.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(
        new google.maps.Point(0, 350)
    );
    neCoords = overlay.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(
        new google.maps.Point(350, 0)
    );

    var bounds = PdfGenerator.data.currentBounds;
    bounds.extend(swCoords);
    bounds.extend(neCoords);

    PdfGenerator.data.smallMap.fitBounds(
        bounds
    );
});
```